# Why can't I create a object in a function in Java?

Tags: java, oop

Code A works well, I think Code B can work correctly, but in fact, Code B doesn't work correctly. Why?

Why can't I create an object in the function-  `private void SetField(Context mContext,MAtt aField,String name)` ?

**Code A**

```
public class MURLPar {

    public MAtt diskcount=new  MAtt();
    public MAtt diskindex=new  MAtt();


    public MURLPar(Context mContext){
        SetField(mContext,diskcount,"Pardiskcount");
        SetField(mContext,diskindex,"Pardiskindex");
    }


    public class MAtt {
        public String name;
        public String value;
    }


    private void SetField(Context mContext,MAtt aField,String name){
        int id = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "string", mContext.getPackageName());
        aField.name=mContext.getString(id);
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
public class MURLPar {

    public MAtt diskcount; 
    public MAtt diskindex;


    public MURLPar(Context mContext){
        SetField(mContext,diskcount,"Pardiskcount");
        SetField(mContext,diskindex,"Pardiskindex");
    }


    public class MAtt {
        public String name;
        public String value;
    }


    private void SetField(Context mContext,MAtt aField,String name){
        aField=new MAtt(); //Create object
        int id = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "string", mContext.getPackageName());
        aField.name=mContext.getString(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `MAtt ` an interface?

Comment: What does the error says?

Comment: The question didn't define clearly about: "Code B don't work correctly". But it is not a compilation error. It may be a business logic error.

Comment: Show how you are calling `SetField()`. Did you assume that after calling `SetField(context, aField, name)`, `aField` **outside** of `SetField()` would change its value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening in code B is that the `MURLPar` constructor passes a reference to `diskcount`/`diskindex` to `SetField`, which within that method has the name `aField`.

You then reassign `aField` with a reference to a newly created object, and you then manipulate that object. Note that `aField` is now referring to a completely separate object, and not whatever it was referring to when you entered `SetField`.

If you're familiar with C you can think of what you're doing here as something along these lines:

```
void SetField(MAtt *aField) {
    aField = (MAtt*) calloc(1, sizeof(MAtt));
}

MAtt *diskcount;
SetField(diskcount);
```

And then expecting `diskcount` to have changed after the call to `SetField`, which it obviously won't have.

---

If you want something like an out parameter, you can simulate that by returning a newly created object:

```
private MAtt SetField(Context mContext, String name){
    MAtt aField = new MAtt(); //Create object
    int id = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "string", mContext.getPackageName());
    aField.name=mContext.getString(id);
    return aField;
}
```

And then:

```
diskcount = SetField(mContext, "Pardiskcount");
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `aField` gets new memory address when you use the command `aField=new MAtt();`

As a result memory address of `diskcount` and `diskindex` remain uninitialized.

For more check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73021/3923800